# How to make a collapse link change from more info to less info

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make my collapse `<a href="#">` go from "more info" to "less info" changing the down-chevrons to up-chevrons and vice versa every time it is clicked

```
<a id="infoToggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#headlineMore" aria-
expanded="false" aria-controls="headlineMore"><span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-down work-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>  More info <span 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down work-list" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

Thank you in advance, please let me know if there is more clarity needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are clearly trying to do this in an accessible way, with the aria attributes you have in your sample code, you can update the chevron with the change in the `aria-expanded` value.

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/scottaohara/eg7hjws8/7/

In the markup, I've changed the link to a button, as this isn't linking anywhere but toggling the state of another element on the page.

```
<button type="button" id="infoToggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#headlineMore" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="headlineMore">
  <span class="state">More</span> info
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down work-list" aria-hidden="true">
  </span>
</button>
```

The jQuery function is simply changing the state of the `aria-expanded` attribute. You will need to add necessary code for toggling the visibility of the targeted element (headlineMore).

```
$('#infoToggle').on('click', function() {
  if ( $(this).attr('aria-expanded') === 'true' ) {
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $(this).find('.state').html('More');
  }
  else {
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
    $(this).find('.state').html('Less');
  }
  /* add in the necessary show/hide toggle for the targeted element here */
});
```

You can see the CSS I threw together in the jsfiddle, though I doubt it's what you will need in your project, so I didn't include it here.

Comment: I also would like to change the text from more to less, then back to more etc.. every time it's pressed. Can this be done in a similar way? Thank you.

Comment: i already updated the code to do just that.... but i see that jsbin doesn't work like codepen, so i need to add a new link.  updating now...

Comment: ok.  link to demo updated and the code in my answer has been updated as well.

Answer (score 2):

Practically you could use simple jQuery on click event to hand it:

```
$('body').on("click", "#infoToggle", function() {
  $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-right')
});
```

Example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kb9dtkb9/)

---

To make text also change you could go with something like the following:

```
$('body').on("click", "#infoToggle", function() {
  var toggle = $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-right');
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).replaceWith(!toggle.hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-down') ? 'More info..' : 'Less info..')
});
```

Example: [jsFiddle/2](https://jsfiddle.net/b1hu08cz/)

Comment: You added chevron down and right, I think that he wants it with chevron up

Comment: @xploshioOn I think it's easy to change `-down` to `-up`. ;)

Comment: I also would like to change the text from more to less, then back to more etc.. every time it's pressed. Thanks

Comment: @Jake I have updated my answer to also toggle the text.